# sql server 2008 select statement for rows count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two table

Table_1:

```
id  pa_name
 1     A
 2     B
 3     C
```

Table_2:

```
id  breakfast   lunch   dinner  day day_des
1      Yes       Yes      No     1    des1
1       No        No      Yes    2    des2
1      Yes        No      Yes    3    des3
2      Yes       Yes      Yes    1    des11
2      Yes        No       No    2    des22
2       No       Yes       No    3    des33
```

I want the result like that

```
id  pa_name breakfast lunch dinner day_des
 1     A       2       1      2     des1
 2     B       2       2      1     des11
```

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine a JOIN with GROUP BY:

```
select t1.id, t1.pa_name,
       SUM(case when breakfast = 'YES' then 1 end) as breakfast,
       SUM(case when lunch = 'YES' then 1 end) as lunch,
       SUM(case when dinner= 'YES' then 1 end) as dinner,
       MIN(day_des)
from Table_1 as t1 join Table_2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.pa_name
```

But I'm a bit concerned about the recent edit, how is day_des supposed to be picked if there are different values? My choice was MIN value.

Comment: is that possible to show all value in day_des column along their id like for id=1 in day_des column value should be des1,des2,des3 @jarlh

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the values in Comma seperated format

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t1.id, t1.pa_name,
           SUM(CASE WHEN breakfast = 'YES' then 1 end) as breakfast,
           SUM(CASE WHEN lunch = 'YES' THEN 1 END) AS lunch,
           SUM(CASE WHEN dinner= 'YES' THEN 1 END) AS dinner       
    FROM Table_1 AS t1 
    JOIN Table_2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.pa_name
)
SELECT *,
SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ', ' + day_des
        FROM TABLE_2 T2 
        WHERE CTE.id=id 
        FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) day_des
FROM CTE
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24cb6/2)**